# Discontinuity in derivative of electric field across non conductive surface

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Let's say I place a positive charge on one side of an infinitely thin layer of non-conducting matter, which stretches out to infinity to ignore edge effects. Should there be a discontinuity in the derivative of the electric field in the direction normal to this layer of matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a charge configuration that depends only on some coordinate $z$, and assuming that the resulting electric field $\vec{E}$ depends only on $z$, then Gauss's Law becomes
$$
\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} = \frac{\rho(z)}{\epsilon_0}
$$
while the non-zero components of Faraday's Law state that
$$
\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial z} = 0.
$$
Thus, the derivative of the $z$-component of $\vec{E}$ is determined by the charge distribution, while the derivatives of the $x$- and $y$-components are always zero (and therefore continuous.)  Whether or not $\partial \vec{E}/\partial z$ is continuous is therefore determined by whether or not $\rho(z)$ is continuous.

For a surface charge $\rho(z) = \sigma \delta(z)$, the derivative of $E_z$ is not well-defined on the surface;  but it is true that
$$
\lim_{z \to 0_+} \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} =\lim_{z \to 0_-}  \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} = 0.
$$
Thus, in the case of a charge confined entirely to the surface, we have
$$
\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial z} = 0
$$
everywhere except on the surface.  This means that the derivatives of $\vec{E}$ "match" (and in fact vanish) above & below the surface;  but it's not technically correct to say that they are continuous at the surface.